# Post form values directly to REST URL

Tags: rest, jsf, jsf-2

im want to know is there any way to post my form values directly to a REST URL

currently im posting like this. Form values will be sent to

```
@managedBean
```

and from managedbean to

```
@service
```

where parsing of xml to objects and building xml objects to send to rest url are carried out from there to

```
@proxy
```

where restcall like

```
@get
@post
@put
@delete
```

are carried out is there any way to post the jsf form values directly tpo post url

Comment: Sure, just use plain HTML instead of JSF. You'll only miss a.o. JSF validation, conversion, listeners, etc.

Comment: is it posible to post directly JSF Form values to RESTURL

Comment: Like stated in the in the comment above: Sure, just use plain HTML instead of JSF. You'll only miss a.o. JSF validation, conversion, listeners, etc. –